# Jquery if condition then change video width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery and I'm having issues with this code. I am trying to set a condition for the #content_container width, and if true, then find all .m4v videos and change their width and height.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

```
$(function() {
    if ((#content_container).width == '600px')
        $('media[src$=".m4v"]').width(400).height(200);
});
```

Comment: `(#content_container)` should probably be `$('#content_container')`. Also, this block will only execute once when the page loads, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if ($('#content_container').width() === 600) {
    $('media[src$=".m4v"]').width(400).height(200);
}
```